# Express, Mongoose, db.findOne always returns same document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am attempting a CRUD app with MEAN stack. I am using mongoose in Express to call to the MongoDB. I am using the FindOne function with a specified parameter, and it's always returning the same (incorrect) document.

I know I am connected to the correct database, since I get a document back from that collection, but it's always the same document, no matter what I pass as the parameter.

```js
module.exports = mongoose.model('Player', playersSchema, 'players'); //in player.js

const Player = require('./model/players');

app.get('/api/player/:id', (req, res) =>{
        Player.findOne({id: req.params.playerId},
            function(err, player) {
                if(err) {
                res.json(err);
                }
                else {
                res.json(player);
                }
            });
    });
```

I have 3 separate "players", with three distinct "playerID" fields (38187361, 35167321, 95821442). I can use Postman to GET the following URL, for example:

http://localhost:3000/api/player/anythingyouWantInHere

and it will return 38187361, the first document. I've been over this website, many tutorials, and the Mongoose documentation and I can't see what I'm doing wrong..

I'd like to eventually find by playerId OR username OR email, but one hurdle at a time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route is '/api/player/:id', so the key on the req.params object will be 'id' not 'playerId'.

I don't know what/where/if you're populating the playerId param, but if you update your query to call req.params.id it should actually change the document based on the path as you seem to be wanting to do.

Comment: this was it. i failed to understand 'req.params.*'

i changed the code to this:
app.get('/api/player/:playerId', (req, res) =>{
        Player.findOne({playerId: req.params.playerId},

Answer (score 1):

From the mongoose documentation of [findOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne), if you pass `Id` a null or an empty value, it will query `db.players.findOne({})` internally which will return first document of the collection everytime you fetch. So make sure you are passing non-empty id here.

> Note: conditions is optional, and if conditions is null or undefined,
>   mongoose will send an empty findOne command to MongoDB, which will
>   return an arbitrary document. If you're querying by _id, use
>   findById() instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it was that the name of column's table was different from the model I had created.
In my model the name of the wrong column was "role" and in my table it was "rol".